# Lucene's StopFilter not removing stopwords?

Tags: java, lucene, stop-words

I built a custom Lucene analyzer for my domain, but after getting unexpected results I decided to get the `TokenStream` for that analyzer and manually debug it.

By doing that I discovered that it doesn't seem to filter my stopwords, and I can't understand why.

Here's the text that I'm using as a test (random twitter item, sorry if it doesn't make any sense):

> Ke #rosicata il #pareggio nel #recupero del #recupero di #vantaggiato del #Livorno a #Catania 1-1 #finale spegne i #sogni degli #etnei di #raggiungere i #playoff per la #promozione in #serieA #catanialivorno square squareformat iphoneography instagramapp uploaded:by=instagram

and these are my stopwords (stored in a file which is loaded by the analyzer):

```
square 
squareformat 
iphoneography 
instagramapp 
uploaded:by=instagram
```

Finally, here's the output (one line = one token):

```
rosicata
pareggio
recupero
recupero
vantaggiato
livorno
catania
finale
finale spegne
spegne
sogni
etnei
raggiungere
playoff
promozione
seriea
seriea catanialivorno
seriea catanialivorno square
catanialivorno
catanialivorno square
catanialivorno square squareformat
square
square squareformat
square squareformat iphoneography
squareformat
squareformat iphoneography
squareformat iphoneography instagramapp
iphoneography
iphoneography instagramapp
instagramapp
instagram
```

As you can see, the last lines contain what I thought to remove with my filter.

Here's filter code:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String string) {
    final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
    src.setMaxTokenLength(DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardFilter(src);
    // From StandardAnalyzer
    tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
    // Custom filters
    // Filter emails, uris and numbers
    Set<String> stopTypes = new HashSet<>();
    stopTypes.add("<URL>");
    stopTypes.add("<NUM>");
    stopTypes.add("<EMAIL>");
    tokenStream = new TypeTokenFilter(tokenStream, stopTypes);
    // Non latin removal
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile("\\P{InBasic_Latin}"), "", true);
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\d).+$"), "", true);
    // Remove words containing www
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile(".*(www).*"), "", true);
    // Remove special tags like uploaded:by=instagram
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile(".+:.+(=.+)?"), "", true);
    // Remove words shorter than 3 characters
    tokenStream = new LengthFilter(tokenStream, 3, 25);
    // Stopwords
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopwordsCollection);
    // N-Grams
    tokenStream = new ShingleFilter(tokenStream, 3);
    // HACK - ShingleFilter uses fillers like _ for some reasons and there's no way to disable it now, so we replace all the _ with empty strings
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile(".*_.*"), "", true);
    tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b"), "", true);
    // Stopwords
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopwordsCollection);
    // Final trim
    tokenStream = new TrimFilter(tokenStream);
    // Set CharTerm attribute
    tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    tokenStream.addAttribute(FuzzyTermsEnum.LevenshteinAutomataAttribute.class);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tokenStream) {
        @Override
        protected void setReader(final Reader reader) {
            src.setMaxTokenLength(DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH);
            super.setReader(reader);
        }
    };        
}
```

Just to double check, I've placed a breakpoint before the return of this method and `stopwordsCollection`, which is a `CharArraySet`, contains the same words that I have in my file (so they're loaded correctly).

My first thought was that Shingle filter was messing with stopwords removal, but now I just saw that the output contains *square* too, which is a single-word stopword.

Can someone help me fixing this?

EDIT: just for clarity I'm also adding the code that I'm using to print tokens.

```
TokenStream tokenStream = null;
try {
    tokenStream = new MyAnalyzer().tokenStream("text", item.toString());
    tokenStream.reset();
    // Iterate over the stream to process single words
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        CharTermAttribute charTerm = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        System.out.println(charTerm.toString());
    }
    // Perform end-of-stream operations, e.g. set the final offset.
    tokenStream.end();
} catch (IOException ex) {
} finally {
    try {
        // Close the stream to release resources
        if (tokenStream != null) {
            tokenStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: turns out that I stored the stopwords with trailing spaces, but there's still one least problem.

Current output is:

```
rosicata
pareggio
recupero
recupero
vantaggiato
livorno
catania
finale
finale spegne
spegne
sogni
etnei
raggiungere
playoff
promozione
seriea
seriea catanialivorno
catanialivorno
instagram
```

As you can see, last word is *instagram*, coming from *uploaded:by=instagram*. Now, *uploaded:by=instagram* is a stopword too, and I'm still using a regex-based filter to remove this kind of patterns

```
tokenStream = new PatternReplaceFilter(tokenStream, Pattern.compile(".+:.+(=.+)?"), "", true);
```

I've also moved it as first filter, still I'm getting *instagram*.

Comment: Your analyzer eliminates stopwords in my test. I'm guessing there is something wrong with how you are loading the stop word set. While debugging, make sure that `stopwordsCollection`'s contents are what you think they should be.

Comment: @femtoRgon thanks for the reply. Updated to op.